# How to non-destructively solidify only certain faces?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

Sometimes I would like to solidify only certain parts of a mesh.  I know I can use the solidify under the *faces* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) menu, but often I would like to do it in a non-destructive manner using the solidify modifier.

The solidify modifier does have an option to solidify only a particular vertex group.  However when I use this option it solidifies (i.e. duplicates) the entire mesh, but only moves out the vertices which are in the vertex group leaving the areas not in the vertex group with double overlapping geometry.  This results in a giant hideous z-fighting mess, as shown below.

[image]

So can I have the solidify modifier apply only to the vertex group and not create this mess?

Comment: Is the goal similar to dynamic paint or displacement by texture?

Comment: Try enabling **Only Rim** in the modifier

Comment: Add a Weld modifier after Solidify modifier.

Answer (score 3):

There are really two ways of handling this issue.

1) As Denis suggested in the comments, check **Only Rim**. This won't give you thickness, but will just displace the faces in the vertex group.

2) Offset the **Factor** a small amount:

[image: factor settings]

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion to use the weld modifier after the solidify modifier might be better since it actually removes the unnecessary geometry which will be way better for performance. If things are welding where you don't want them to experiment the weld modifier's settings and see how it works.